# Run a specified NUnit test as a 32-bit process in a 64-bit environment

Tags: c#, nunit, teamcity, oledb

I have a component that uses OLEDB to import data from an Excel file. Due to business risk and time constraints, my executable shell is compiled as x86 (32-bit) to avoid the [64-bit OLEDB problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/d5b29496-d6a1-4ecf-b1a4-5550d80b84b6/) and the component runs flawlessly when loaded into my 32-bit shell.

However, my CI build process (TeamCity) is running its TestRunner in a 64-bit process and so unit tests targeting the above functionality are failing with the usual error message:

> Test(s) failed. System.InvalidOperationException : The
>   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine

My solutions would appear to be

1. Change the CI test runner - not feasible as the testrunner is used by 10 other teams
2. Ensure this test is run in a 32-bit process

So, is there a way to tell NUnit, or the TeamCity NUnit test runner, to run a specific test in a 32-bit process? Ideally, I'd like the same tests to run unmodified in both IDE and CI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the "Platform target" to x86 on the unit test project should do the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't that affect the entire Test Project? I guess the OP wants to do this for a test specifically.

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan: Yes, it would affect the entire Test Project. As the complete application is executed as x86 I figured it should be OK when the complete test suite is executed as x86, too.

Comment: Fair enough to me, maybe @MarkGreen could decide.

Comment: I'd be much shinier if there were a test-level granularity solution but I suppose I could always create a 1-component test assembly.